# npm install --save not installing the module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, sendgrid

I am integrating firebase cloud functions with my app's workflow. I needed to install a package so I did `npm install --save @sendgrid/mail`. The installation was a success but I can't see the dependency either in node_modules folder or the package.json file. What do I do?

Comment: Can you post the error message you're getting from npm?

Answer (score 1):

One way to add the package would be to do the reverse. Add `@sendgrid/mail` to your `package.json` with the version you want, and then run `npm install`.

Comment: I still get an error 'Cannot find module @sendgrid/mail'